# Grails 1.3.9 parse JSON file

Tags: json, grails, jsonslurper

I am working on a project with Grails 1.3.9 and I need to parse a `JSON` file and read some values. This can be easily done with `JsonSlurper` but it is supported only for Grails 1.8 and higher. Are there any other techniques to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
def parsedJSON = JSON.parse(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Readers in the future woun't use Grails 1.3.9 :)

Comment: Sounds possible :)